# Is it okay to have poor answers partly consisting of the existing answers that were posted long ago?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

Specifically, I'm talking about this answer: https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/14231/5788

I see such stuff every day on programming and development sites of SE network, and I can understand that because sometimes the code is a bit different, but this here is pretty much a case of a useless answer. What does this site's policy say?

Comment: **Here is my approach to this kind of answers** - Leave a comment to address user that his answer doesn't adding any value to existing answer Or your answer is same as accepted answer. You can use down-vote if looks applicable or flag it if its spam(doesn't answering and looks as comment).

Comment: There isn't a flag reason for that currently, and I don't think that answer can be improved to include more detail (the question has been answered well enough in my opinion). This answer is posted by an unregistered user, so he's probably not gonna come back editing or improving it. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: For this case flagging looks inappropriate but down-vote and comment looks appropriate to me. Sometimes unregistered users also comes back, so we can't be sure about it. And leaving comment is always a good habit.

Answer (score 5):

There are two approaches to "low quality" answers.

One is to comment and downvote, especially if the answer does have some useful content.

The other is to comment and flag (there is a flag for "very low quality"), especially if the answer does have any useful content not present in other answers. It is important to comment, clearly and specifically, the shortcomings of any answer that is flagged so that the moderator (who may not be familiar with the subject) will be able to determine the correct action.